# Get location for Azure VM classic using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Using powershell how do I get the location of a VM classic using powershell. Get-AzureVM does not seem to have this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We couldn't get the Azure VM location from the `Get-AzureVM` directly, but we could get it from the VM disk.Please have try to use the following code.

```
$serviceName = "xxxx"
$vmName ="xxxx"
$vm= Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName 
$disk =  Get-AzureDisk -DiskName  $vm.VM.OSVirtualHardDisk.DiskName
$location = $disk.Location
```

[image]